# Layout similar to google chrome application tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I want to use a multiple column reactive layout where each column will have an image and below a title, as used in google chrome application tab.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: what exactly do you mean? can you give an example?

Comment: @KeesSonnema I think he's referring to this layout: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Comment: unfortunately I still can not send pictures.
Open Chrome
go into Application Tab (where you can see the applications for chrome: for example Store, GMail, etc.) I would like to create a html page similar

Comment: ah i get it. now i understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do this with thumbsnails. 
you can use a table grid layout so they align up nice.

a demo here. http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/cssthumbnailgrid/

the tutorial for this here: http://designshack.net/articles/css/creating-a-css-thumbnail-grid-with-dynamic-flyout-menu/

You can just make a grid layout and put images in there and a title above it.

More about grid layouts: http://www.ehow.com/how_6317944_make-table-grid.html

Hope it helps you. i see no other way to do that. but when i come across a better solution i will edit this answer.

Comment: Thank you, but I look for a solution like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cxfFL/
I would like to implement image scaling (auto resize)

Comment: maybe this helps http://www.demacmedia.com/design-user-experience/mini-tutorial-%E2%80%93-responsive-image-grid-using-only-css-cross-browser-compatible/

Comment: I should be able to solve my problem.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I can not vote because my reputation is less than 15

Comment: it's allright. an accept is enough :)